# How to debug a 502 error for a Docker compose app?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose

An application that I'm maintaining (I'm not the one who created it, so my knowledge of it is limited) is deployed via Docker compose and consists of the following containers:

```
name                 what is            status
servey_prod_bot      a Telegram bot     works
...                  helper services for bot, of no interest in this context
servey_prod_stat     reports new data   works
servey_prod_app      admin web app      not accessible (see below)
servey_prod_nginx    well, Nginx        works
servey_prod_db       db                 works
```

Recently, I was asked to modify the _stat component, and, long story short, that forced me to rebuild the whole thing and restart the containers, and some code changes might get applied. The _bot and the _stat seem to work nicely, the _app is also up, but now an attempt to get it via browser fails with 502.

What I have done to debug this already:

- the _app (it's a Django app):

  - I've checked `docker logs` and shows that it successfully started gunicorn, listens to `http://0.0.0.0:9090` and has 3 workers (on restart workers exited and the app is shut down, then restarted successfully; no migrations involved);
  - I've also checked `nc -zv localhost 9090` and `nc -zv 0.0.0.0 9090` inside the container, both report that the port is `open`;
  - finally, I've checked that `python manage.py check` responds with `System check identified no issues (0 silenced).`.
- the nginx:

  - it's up alright (`docker ps -a` reports that, the 502 response is from it);
  - I'm 100% sure that the configs were not changed since the time of the successful run (when everything work as expected);
  - `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` inside the container has this entry (note: container names were not changed as well, so the `app` bit here seem to correspond to the name in `docker-compose.yml` and not to the actual container name)

    ```
        location /admin {^M
            proxy_pass http://app:9090;^M
        }^M
    ```
  - docker logs (nginx logs) show that, well, the routes of interest got some 200s in the past (27.09) and 502s recently (on attempts to open them);
- the `docker-compose.yml`:

  - also wasn't changed since when everything worked;
  - among services, it has `app: &app_t` one, which is the Django app, and it doesn't specify anything about the port 9090; and it has `nginx:` one that exposes `- "<extenal_port>:80"`, where `<extenal_port>` is the one by which I'm trying to access the web app (as previously).

My question is: how to further debug this? I probably lack deep understanding how Docker compose networking works, so I have vague idea how to debug this end-to-end.

Additional notes:

- previous build was looong time ago (many months);
- I thought that `docker network inspect` may show some more details, but it doesn't even show the exposed/used ports;
- `docker-compose version 1.29.2`.

Comment: One option can be to start from Django app, open interactive shell and try the same request (with appropriate hostname) inside the container. If it works, try the same request from the nginx container